# Do I have to use the perfect infinitive

Tags: perfect-constructions

I was taught that if we had some action which can happen before some moment in the future, I had to use Perfect. For example:

> I will have done it by the morning.

Some days ago I had to say a sentence like this:

> I will want to (come) by the beginning of the meeting.

And I was stuck because I thought the action "to come" had to be with perfect because it could happen before some moment in the future. It would look like this:

> I will want to have come by the beginning of the meeting.

But then I thought it would mean something different because the sentence

> I want to have come by the evening = I want so I would have come by
> the evening

mean that I want something what could have happened in the past but not later the wanting moment, not later than now, not in the future.

The sentence

> I wanted to have come

means the same(as I know). I wanted something what could have happened even before the wanting moment, not later than it, not in the future but only in the past.

And If I say:

> I will want to have come by the beginning of the meeting

it may mean that I will want something what didn't happen in the past happen in this past. But my sense is the action "to come by the beginning..." is not earlier than the wanting moment, it's in the future.

If I can say for this so:

> I will want to come by the evening

meaning that the "come" action is in the future for 'will want", then it's perfect.

If I can say:

> I will want to have come by the evening

meaning that the "come" action is in the past for "will want", then it's clear.

If to ask shortly, we have two sentences:

> I want to come by the evening
>
> I want to have come by the evening

Are they correct and what do they mean?

Answer (score 2):

The sentence

> I will want to have come by the evening.

Implies that you don't want it now, but will later. This is almost surly not the intended  meaning.

While it is possible to say:

> I want to have come by the evening.

it is awkward and technically incorrect. It would probably be understood, but would not sound right. Moreover, there is another possible sense which is grammatically correct but almost surely not intended, where "come" has a sexual meaning.  Anyone thinking of this meaning would be amused and distracted.

As Astralbee indicated, it is much better to use 'arrived' here:

> I want to have arrived by the evening.

However, for informal speech, one might better say

> I want to be there by the evening.

or

> I want to get there by the evening.

The second stresses arrival, the first presence, but in practice the meanings are essentially the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example shows the correct use of the future perfect tense:

> I will have done it by the morning.

"Have done" alone would present perfect - the rest of the sentence puts it into future perfect. But note that "done" means *completed*. It is the *past participle* of the verb "*to do*".

Your question is about:

> I will want to have come by the beginning of the meeting.

This is *incorrect*. "Come" is the *base form* of the verb so it does not fit this sentence the same way "done" does is in the previous example.

Your sentence should really say:

> I will want to have *arrived* by the beginning of the meeting.

"Arrived" is most appropriate because the verb "to come" implies movement towards something, so no form of this verb really describes you having completed this journey and arrived at your given time.

This is the case for all your subsequent examples:

> <s>I want to come by the evening</s>
>   I want to arrive by the evening.
>
> <s>I want to have come by the evening</s>
>   I want to have arrived by the evening.

Both mean the same - that you want to be there by (before) evening. Using the future perfect tense is often a choice, unlike when you are speaking about past and present events when you must use the correct tense else make a grammatical error. The future perfect tense is a different way of speaking about future events, projecting ourselves forward into the future so that we can then look back at an action that will be completed later. It is a choice like using active or passive voice - the meaning is ultimately the same.

Be aware though that this is not a rule for all verbs - some just do not work in the future perfect tense - *Come/Came* being a prime example. Another is *do/done*. If you say that you want "to do" something by a specific time it does not necessarily mean you will have it *completed* by that time, so the two are not interchangeable as one may describe the *start* and another the *end* of an action. You should consider each verb and what it implies to see if it makes sense using it in the future perfect tense. If it does not, use a word that more accurately suits the completed state.

Comment: Okay, but the question was not about this.

What is the difference between "I want to come by the evening" and "I want to have come by the evening"?

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko Both are incorrect. They should be "I want to arrive by the evening" and "I want to have arrived by the evening", which my answer explains. They essentially mean the same, just using different tense, which you seem to already understand.

Comment: But "I want to arrive by the evening" means the arrival will be after the wanting while "I want to have arrived" means I want so I would have arrived where the arrival is before the wanting, it was or wasn't in the past.

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko I've added some detail to try and answer that, but the *meaning* of both is the same even though the *tense* is different. Future perfect tense is a way of saying the same thing from a different perspective. You place yourself in the future so that a nearer future event can be spoken of in the past. But those in the present understand that the meaning is the same.

Comment: Then due to your logic the next sentences should be equal for their sense: 1) I want to do 2) I want to have done

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko Hmmm it depends on what follows. "I want to do my homework by..." doesn't necessarily mean *completed*, whereas "I want to have done my homework by..." does mean finished. You need to think about the action implied by the verb. This is why I explained that "came" isn't appropriate in your examples because, despite being past tense, does not convey the completion by the given time.

Comment: We don't get each other. 
Let it be shown thus: I want(now, on Monday) to do it by Tuesday. The "to do" action is a future action for the moment when I want it(on Monday).
If I say: "I want (now, on Monday) to have done it by "Tuesday", would it mean the same that the "to have done" action is future(Tuesday) for the wanting moment(now, on Monday) or it will be like: "I wish(now, on Monday) I had done it by Tuesday" when the "had done" is past for the wanting moment and this Tuesday is one of the Tuesdays which were earlier, in the past but not in the future after this current Monday?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91593/discussion-between-astralbee-and-michael-azarenko).

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko "I want to have done it by Tuesday" is a perfectly grammatical sentence in everyday use. But it is not a future perfect. "To have done it by Tuesday" is a noun phrase, and the object of the verb "want".  It is a sort of perfect infinitive. which the title to your question mentions. "By Tuesday I shall wish I had done it on Monday." That is a sort of future pluperfect - and perfectly idiomatic.  I would suggest that has a place in your thinking somewhere.